# Retrieving only one file that matches the pattern

Tags: python, regex

My directory holds a bunch of files

```
chr2.fa      chr2.fa.ann  chr2.fa.fai  chr2.fa.sa
chr2.fa.amb  chr2.fa.bwt  chr2.fa.pac
```

**The directory I want to search is in `dir_path` and what I want the function to return as `reference_name` is only chr2.fa with the path**

I tried to use `r.match('.*\.fa$', filename)`:

But this did not work. Any suggestion to resolve this will be very helpful.

```
def searchforfile(dir_path):
    for files in os.listdir(dir_path):
        fileName,fileExtension = os.path.splitext(files)
        if fileExtension=='.fa':
            print 'This file is fa file %s' %files
            reference_name = dir_path + '/' + files
            return reference_name[0]
        elif  fileExtension=='.fasta':
            print 'This file is fasta file %s' %files
            reference_name = dir_path + '/' + files
            return reference_name[0]
        else:
            print 'Format is not valid'
```

**The result I get with this method is:**

```
    index file /.fai not found, generating...

    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

      what():  vector::_M_range_check

    Format is not valid

    Format is not valid

    Format is not valid

    Format is not valid

This file is fa file chr2.fa
```

Comment: How on earth are you getting a C++ error message?

Comment: Its probably becos the plugin is developed for galaxy like interface.

Comment: That code will never throw that error. Also, it seems to find the one file with a `.fa` extension. What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: The code I think is looking for the next file example /.fai And that is not what I want. I just want to strictly look for .fa and get out of the loop. I did try with break but it didnt really stop looking for the fai files

Comment: It will exit the function as soon as it finds something. `return` terminates the execution of a function.

Comment: `r.match('.*\.fa$', filename)` doesn't work because filename doesn't have the extension, which has been extracted out by  `os.path.splitext`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `end` function of the match object to check if there is something else after `.fa`.

```
import re
import os

def searchforfile(dir_path, pattern='.*\.fa'):
    r = re.compile(pattern)
    for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
        m = r.match(f)
        if m and m.end() == len(f):
            print 'This file is a fa file: %s'%f
        elif m:
            print 'This file contains more text after fa: %s'%f
        else:
            print 'This file does not contain the fa extension: %s'%f
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as the chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is currently returning `/` and not the entire file name and path. Change your return statement to:

```
return reference_name
```

**Why?**
`reference_name` is a string. If you `return reference_name[0]`, then you are just returning the first element of the string. For example,

```
reference_name = '/Users/fasta_files/chr2.fa'
>>>reference_name[0]
/
>>>reference_name
'/Users/fasta_files/chr2.fa'
```

Answer (score -3):

I modified my earlier code and that worked aswell.

```
def searchforfile(dir_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
        logfile.write(filename+"\n")
        if filename.endswith('fa'):
            reference_name = dir_path + '/' + filename,'r'
            return reference_name[0]
        elif filename.endswith('fasta'):
            reference_name = dir_path + '/' + filename,'r'
            return reference_name[0]
        else:
            print ("Reference file was not found")
```

Comment: @Why did you add the `r`? Does it have some significance? You could just do `return reference_name` and not have to add `r`